# Auto launch program when I plug raspi into computer?

Tags: filesystem

As the title says, is it possible to launch an exe or run a command when I plug my raspberry pi into my computer so that the program launches ON THE PC/MAC. I know you can auto boot something when you plug in a usb drive but I’m not sure how you would achieve the same thing with the pi.

Comment: What do you mean by plugging the raspberry pi into computer? Pls be specific. How you are connecting your raspberry pi to the computer?

Comment: My apologies! Just a simple 3.0 USB cord

Comment: @user2544427, to launch a program on the PC/MAC, you'd have to run something on that computer. I reccomend a Python script for that, Mac already has Python2 preinstalled. Of course, the RPi could emulate some sort of media device (which would be complicated) but would only allow a default dialog.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But running programs on a PC/MAC is off-topic here on Raspberry Pi. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here. You should ask in an appropriate forum.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer but I do have an alternative I'm probably going to try myself.

At the end of the day the goal is to plug in a device and require little to no setup correct?
My idea is to connect the raspberry pi in [gadget mode](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget?view=all) using the [`gadget_cdrom`](https://github.com/tjmnmk/gadget_cdrom#readme) library.
Then you can write a program in python or something to make it cross platform, provide an exe for windows and add an `autoplay.inf` [see how to here](https://www.discwizards.com/how-to-create-an-autorun-cd.htm).

*I'm pretty sure most pc's don't allow for autorun anymore but at least it'll allow anyone to just click the drive icon and start the program on windows.*

Then in your python app you can just ssh to `raspberrypi.local` or something like that. And on the raspi side create a user that can only run one ssh command for the python program.